# Advanced Custom Fields: Conditional Statement with Select

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, conditional-tags

I've set up a select field labeled "asset_type" with two values: "image" and "video".  I then have two fields that rely on conditional logic to be displayed.  If "image" is selected from the select I show the "image_asset" field, and if "video" is selected from the select I show the "video_asset" field.  Reading through the docs and a few other stack questions, I thought I had the logic setup correctly, but for the life of me can not get the content to display.  This is what my code looks like:

```
<?php if(get_sub_field('asset_type') == "image") { ?>

    <div><?php the_sub_field('image_asset'); ?></div>

<?php } ?>

<?php if(get_sub_field('asset_type') == "video") { ?>

    <div><?php the_sub_field('video_asset'); ?></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: did you try to echo get_sub_field('asset_type') to see whats returning? are you using repeater fields? otherwise, don't you want to use get_field() instead?

Comment: @peteroak thanks for replying!  This block actually resides inside of a repeater field, and that's why I'm using sub_field.  Echoing get_sub_field('asset_type') returns Image as text. Hmmm.

Comment: on the good track then! well, thats it then: == "Image"

Comment: in case you didn't see the edit, you its capital I instead of i

Comment: HAH! That did it @peteroak. I can't believe I missed something so trivial.  Capitalizing Image and Video in the PHP and all is working as expected.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of closing the question:

```
<?php if(get_sub_field('asset_type') == "Image") { ?>
  <div><?php the_sub_field('image_asset'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if(get_sub_field('asset_type') == "Video") { ?>
  <div><?php the_sub_field('video_asset'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the `value` of your select field instead of the label in your statement you can do this in ACF:

```
image : Image
video : Video
```

And this in your template (using the value not the human readable label):

```
<?php if(get_sub_field('asset_type', '') == "image") { ?>
  <div><?php the_sub_field('image_asset'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if(get_sub_field('asset_type', '') == "video") { ?>
  <div><?php the_sub_field('video_asset'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here `get_sub_field('asset_type')` has been changed to `get_sub_field('asset_type', '')`

This is a much cleaner option when faced with long labels e.g.

```
video : First Event Video 1920x1080
```

It also allows you to quickly change the label for the user without having to rework your code.